# Python memory leakage in multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-3.6, python-multiprocessing

I am working on some computations in Python using multiprocess (`concurrent.futures`), however, I notice that there is some memory leakage happening, it seems the memory used by subprocesses are not freed after the subprocess finishes computation, I have attached a simplified example. Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug in Python? I have tested Python3.6 and Python3.8. Any suggestion on how to debug it will be very helpful, thank you!

```
import os
import gc
import random
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed


data_list = []

def _gen_rand_data(n1, n2):
    global data_list
    for _ in range(n1): 
        d = {}
        for _ in range(n2): 
            d[str(random.randint(1e6, 1e12))+"87654321"] = str(random.randint(1e6, 1e16))+"12345678"
        data_list.append(d)


def _compute_subprocess(j):
    global data_list
    set_j_sum = sum([int(x) for x in data_list[j].values()])
    ret_list = []

    for i in range(0, j): 
        overlap_key_sum = 0
        for k, v in data_list[i].items():
            if k in data_list[j]:
                overlap_key_sum += int(v)
        ret_list.append(overlap_key_sum/set_j_sum)

    gc.collect()
    return ret_list


def compute(): 
    global data_list
    _gen_rand_data(2000, 2000)
    final_data = [[-1]*len(data_list) for _ in range(len(data_list))]

    futures_dict = {}
    finish_cnt = 0

    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=os.cpu_count()) as ppe:
        for j in range(1, len(data_list)):
            futures_dict[ppe.submit(_compute_subprocess, j)] = j

        for future in as_completed(futures_dict): 
            ret_list = future.result()
            j = futures_dict[future]
            for i in range(len(ret_list)):
                final_data[i][j] = ret_list[i]
            finish_cnt += 1
            print("{}/{}".format(finish_cnt, len(data_list)))
            gc.collect()

    return final_data


compute()
```

As suggested, I have also tried `multiprocessing`, the code is attached, it still has the same problem.

```
import os
import gc
import random
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Pool


data_list = []
final_data = None

def _gen_rand_data(n1, n2):
    global data_list
    for _ in range(n1): 
        d = {}
        for _ in range(n2): 
            d[str(random.randint(1e6, 1e12))+"87654321"] = str(random.randint(1e6, 1e16))+"12345678"
        data_list.append(d)


def _compute_subprocess(j):
    global data_list, final_data
    set_j_sum = sum([int(x) for x in data_list[j].values()])

    for i in range(0, j): 
        overlap_key_sum = 0
        for k, v in data_list[i].items():
            if k in data_list[j]:
                overlap_key_sum += int(v)
        final_data[i][j] = overlap_key_sum/set_j_sum

    gc.collect()


def compute(): 
    global data_list, final_data
    _gen_rand_data(2000, 2000)
    # _gen_rand_data(10, 10)
    final_data = [[-1]*len(data_list) for _ in range(len(data_list))]
    finish_cnt = 0

    proc_list = []
    with Pool() as pool:
        pool.map(_compute_subprocess, iterable=range(1, len(data_list)))

    print(len(final_data))

compute()
```

Comment: Does `_compute_subprocess` have access to `data_list` after it is submitted to the pool? Have you tried a small `data_set`, like `(3,3)`? Do you get the correct results?

Comment: Yes, it has access, the results are correct. My first version of this is to pass the sub-list via pipe, but it causes too much data movement, so I used a global variable which I hope to take advantage of copy-on-write.

Comment: As a comment, I must have done something stupid, because a similar computation I wrote yesterday (forgot to commit :( ) didn't have this problem, but now it also has memory leakage.

Comment: Well with a 10x10 I can see the processes spool up then disappear along with their memory. I had to put a `try/except` around `set_j_sum = sum([int(x) for x in data_list[j].values()])` to catch an IndexError - I had it return `data_list` in the except suite and it returns an empty list.

Comment: If I comment out `global data_list` in `_compute_subprocess`  then add a list of dicts to it, it runs just fine and doesn't throw an IndexError.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but may I ask why you chose `concurrent.futures` over `multiprocessing`?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile - I like it because of the *built-in*  infrastructure - batteries included.

Comment: @wwii can you be more specific about the index error you had? I tried to put the `try/except` around that line, but I didn't have any error, if there is an index error, it might because of that.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile no specific reason, I used multiprocessing in the past, but then I noticed `concurrent.futures` and I feel like it is easier to use and make the code shorter. The script I wrote is a simple data processing script (100-200 lines), using `multiprocessing.Pool`, I won't be able to monitor the progress, while if I do async, the code will be much longer. But the way, I just tried `multiprocessing`, it sill has the same problem.

Comment: `concurrent.futures.process._RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python36\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 175, in _process_worker
    r = call_item.fn(*call_item.args, **call_item.kwargs)
  File "C:\pyprojects33\foo.py", line 21, in _compute_subprocess
    set_j_sum = sum([int(x) for x in data_list[j].values()])
IndexError: list index out of range
"""
`